# Android. Пропадают данные из вкладок на фрагментах

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-manager

Реализовал вкладки по инструкции http://www.fandroid.info/android-material-design-rabota-s-vkladkami/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая вкладка фрагмент, данные подгружаются из активити

```
AmurApi amurApi = new HttpService().call();
final Call<WorkModel> work = amurApi.getWorkDetail(idOrg, orgTicketCode);
work.enqueue(getWorkCallback());

private Callback<WorkModel> getWorkCallback() {
    return new Callback<WorkModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WorkModel> call, Response<WorkModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "Данные по работе получены");
                WorkModel data = response.body();
                TextView orgTicketCodeView = findViewById(R.id.orgTicketCodeView);
                orgTicketCodeView.setText(data.getOrgTicketCode());
                TextView cstWorkNameView = findViewById(R.id.typeWorkView);
                cstWorkNameView.setText(data.getCstWorkName());
                TextView orgStatusCodeTextView = findViewById(R.id.orgStatusCodeTextView);
                orgStatusCodeTextView.setText(data.getOrgStatusCodeText());
            } else {
                Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity response code " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WorkModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Config.TAG_DEBUG, "WorkActivity failure " + t);
        }
    };
}
```

И так для каждой вкладки. Когда из вкладки РАБОТА переходишь в КЛИЕНТ и потом обратно, то данные сохраняются. Но если последовательно перейти РАБОТА->КЛИЕНТ->АДРЕС и также вернуться назад, то данные на вкладке РАБОТА пропадают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть у меня предоположение, что получение данных через Retrofit и их отображение должно быть в самом фрагменте в OnCreate, а не в активити. Вот только не понятно как. Есть советы использовать аргументы и потом их восстанавливать, другие говорят что запросы Retrofit делать во фрагменте и там же использовать View для вывода значений.

Подскажите правильное решение.

Comment: Проблема в том что он хранит только 3 фрагмента (текущий, предыдущий, следующий) решается указанием количества фрагментов что нужно одновременно хранить внутри viewpager. 
down vote
Simply set the offscreen limit to one.

ViewPager mViewpager = (ViewPager)findView....
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5) -

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych спасибо. Добавил viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5); и данные не пропадают. Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что он хранит только 3 фрагмента (текущий, предыдущий, следующий) решается указанием количества фрагментов что нужно одновременно хранить внутри viewpager. 
ViewPager mViewpager = (ViewPager)findView...
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5) - нужное количество фрагментов